# knitr markdown not displaying basic plot in r

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, histogram, knitr

I am trying to print a simple plot with knitr markdown.

below is my code.

````
```{Simple plot}
library(datasets)
with(airquality, plot(Wind, Ozone))
```
````

If I run this in r code file, it returns the plot properly.

However, when running this in a markdown file, it only shows code but no plot to the printed document.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried `with(airquality, print(plot(Wind, Ozone)))` but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ```{r} where `r` means R langage :

````
```{r}
library(datasets)
with(airquality, plot(Wind, Ozone))
```
````